# CSS Only Slider Button Hover Issue - modified from AMKohn's CodePen

Tags: html, css, slider, radio-button, label

I found a neat CSS Slider by AMKohn:

http://codepen.io/AMKohn/pen/EKJHf

The slider works by using radio buttons and labels to move between 'slides'.

Slides are hidden by default and are displayed when their respective radio buttons are checked.

I've modified the slider so that each photo is accompanied by a caption below it that extends the width of the browser.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AlsJx/

As a result, my mark-up and CSS are a little different from the original, but the principals are still the same (still uses labels and radio buttons to move between slides).

I think this is affecting the labels (which act as nav buttons). These do not display on hover when using

```
position:absolute;
```

However, when the `position` is set to `relative` the buttons work fine except they are not in the right place (on either side of the photos).

Can someone explain how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue.

Essentially, the problem was due to using `position:absolute` on the parent element `.slides`.

I made it `display:hidden` by default and `display:block` when `input:checked`.

This prevented the divs from "stacking", which I concluded (in a very non-technical way) was the reason why the nav buttons didn't work.

The working slider is here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hAnre/